# Smoother scroll transitions in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax effect in firefox by modifying the top position of elements using the onscroll event. I throttled the onscroll event so it doesn't overload the browser and I added a transition top property in the css to make things smoother. This works pretty well in every browser, but firefox is extremely choppy for some reason. Is there any way to make this transition smoother?

```js
window.onscroll = throttle(function(){
  var scrollDistance = window.pageYOffset || window.document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById("back").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.3 + "px";
  document.getElementById("mid").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.5 + "px";
  document.getElementById("fore").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.9 + "px";
}, 100);

function throttle (callback, limit) {
    var wait = false;
    return function () {
        if (!wait) {
            callback.call();
            wait = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                wait = false;
            }, limit);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 5000px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1920-1920-4.jpg);
}

.parallaxEl {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.1s;
}

#back{
  background: url(http://wall.rimbuz.com/wp-content/uploads/4K-Wide-Wallpapers.jpg);
}

#mid{
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/space_planet_background_83807_3840x2160.jpg);
}

#fore{
  background: url(http://wall.rimbuz.com/wp-content/uploads/4K-HD-Background-Wallpapers.jpg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="back"></div>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="mid"></div>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="fore"></div>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAzBrX

Answer (score 0):

When possible you should use CSS 3D Transforms for animation because it has access to a users GPU and allows for smoother animation.

**Hardware Acceleration and CSS Animation**

https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/

---

Also, here is an example of a basic parallax effect using this technique...

https://css-tricks.com/tour-performant-responsive-css-site/#article-header-id-2

Answer (score 0):

Using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), you'll get a smoother throttler.

`requestAnimationFrame` has the advantage to be synced with the screen refresh rate.

Here is a code demo :

```js
// your callback
var scrollHandler = function() {
  var scrollDistance = window.pageYOffset || window.document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById("back").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.3 + "px";
  document.getElementById("mid").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.5 + "px";
  document.getElementById("fore").style.top = -scrollDistance * 0.9 + "px";
};

// the throttle function
// returns the function that should be passed has an event listener
var throttle = function(callback) {
  // a simple flag
  var active = false;
  // to keep track of the last event
  var evt;
  // fired only when screen has refreshed
  var handler = function(){
    // release our flag 
    active = false;
    // call the callback
    callback(evt);
    }
  // the actual event handler
  return function handleEvent(e) {
    // save our event at each call
    evt = e;
    // only if we weren't already doing it
    if (!active) {
      // raise the flag
      active = true;
      // wait for next screen refresh
      requestAnimationFrame(handler);
    };
  }
}
// remember to call the function, we need its returned function
window.onscroll = throttle(scrollHandler);
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1920-1920-4.jpg);
}
.parallaxEl {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.1s;
}
#back {
  background: url(http://wall.rimbuz.com/wp-content/uploads/4K-Wide-Wallpapers.jpg);
}
#mid {
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/space_planet_background_83807_3840x2160.jpg);
}
#fore {
  background: url(http://wall.rimbuz.com/wp-content/uploads/4K-HD-Background-Wallpapers.jpg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="back"></div>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="mid"></div>
  <div class="parallaxEl" id="fore"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event 'onscroll' is caused after a scroll, and the event 'onmousewheel' ('onwheel') is caused after a scroll. For a scroll using a mouse animation will be more smoothly.

Example here: [excube.hol.es](http://www.excube.hol.es)