# Is there an optimization in canceling request animation frame?

Tags: javascript, scroll, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

Would there be any benefit(or even possible in `window.cancelAnimationFrame();` this example below?

If so, How would I do so, and why?

[Ref: requestAnimationFrame MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // do something with the scroll position
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });
  }
  ticking = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid the anonymous function by passing directly `doSomething` as the rAF parameter and by including the `ticking = false` directly in `doSomething`.

You can also remove the `last_known_scroll_position` variable declaration since it's just `window.scrollY`, which also removes the need to have a parameter to `doSomething`. 
By the way, it's better to use `pageYOffset` than `scrollY`, for wider browser support.

Otherwise, your logic is the good one.

This flag will avoid stacking an other function call when one is already waiting, and the use of `cancelAnimationFrame` would have just unecessarely filled your memory with the creation of this anonymous function, forcing a premature GC kick.

So once everything is applied, you've got something like :

```js
var ticking = false;

function doSomething() {
  ticking = false;
  var scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
  // do something with the scroll position

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);
  }
  ticking = true;
});
```

Comment: Ps : for a more generic throttler, I wrote one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38626349/3702797)